# What is the maximum expiration time for CloudFront signed url

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront for generating signed URL from this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CFPrivateDistJavaDevelopment.html) what is the maximum expiration time for CloudFront signed URL?  How should I mention on this DateLessThan argument

**Sample Code snippet**

```
String signedUrlCanned = CloudFrontService.signUrlCanned(
    "http://" + distributionDomain + "/" + s3ObjectKey, // Resource URL or Path
    keyPairId,     // Certificate identifier, 
                   // an active trusted signer for the distribution
    derPrivateKey, // DER Private key data
    ServiceUtils.parseIso8601Date("2011-11-14T22:20:00.000Z") // DateLessThan
    );
System.out.println(signedUrlCanned);
```

**Note**: It should be a permanent URL like Instagram cdn URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no maximum expiration time for CloudFront signed URLs but you always have to specify the `DateLessThan` parameter.

CloudFront requires this value to prevent users from having permanent access to your private content.

In order to have a permanent-like URL you should set the `DateLessThan` far in the future.

Also see [When Does CloudFront Check the Expiration Date and Time in a Signed URL?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-check-expiration) and [Creating a Signed URL Using a Custom Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-values)