# How to give long term read access to objects in a private s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Well I have a service which generate PDF files every day and I need to share a download link to this pdf files through email to send to our clients.

I am thinking to save these files to a s3 bucket, but we need to make sure these download links will works all the time, I went through `Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URLs` but asfaik presigned urls only valid for a `maximum of 7 days` but the links should be valid all the time, is there any other way to give access to s3 objects for longer term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to generate Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs with a validity of more than one week.

For longer term, you need to use CloudFront Signed URLs for which you can set an expiry date far in the future.

See [Serving Private Content with Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) and [Using Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) in the CloudFront documentation and [Using CloudFront Signed URLs to Serve Private S3 Content](https://medium.com/roam-and-wander/using-cloudfront-signed-urls-to-serve-private-s3-content-e7c63ee271db) on Medium.

Comment: What is the maximum expiry date by using CloudFront?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723691/what-is-the-maximum-expiration-time-for-cloudfront-signed-url/55729193#55729193

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom download link that hits your backend service (use a jwt, or something else with expiry of your choice).

After validating the JWT on your server, generate a new S3 Pre-signed link(short expiry) and proceed with download.